# Duda sobre la implementacion de un BottomNavigationBar en un StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

mi duda radica en la implementacion de un BottomNavigationBar en el codigo que tengo ahora mismo para gestionar unas estadisticas.
El problema es que el bottomnavigationabar lo cree despues del codigo asi que ahora tengo un problema a la hora de integrarlo a mi codigo, dado que tengo un Material y un StreamBuilder, y segun he leido el BottomNavigationBar se suele poner con Scaffold.

Intente intregrarlo directamente pero nada, luego pasadolo a una clase y llamandola pero nada , tambien converti la clase original a StateFull para poder cambiar de estado (en el bottomNav).

Como aclaracion lo quiero integrar en el build de _EstadisticasState.

```
import 'package:fancy_bottom_navigation/fancy_bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/funcions/main_highscores.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/models/highscore.dart';
import 'package:reactions/src/models/tipos_modos.dart';


class Estadisticas extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EstadisticasState createState() => _EstadisticasState();
}

class _EstadisticasState extends State<Estadisticas> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MainHighscores mainHighscores = Provider.of<MainHighscores>(context);
  int currentPage = 1;
  GlobalKey bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

    return Material(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Highscore>>(
            stream: mainHighscores.highscore$,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Container();
              }
              double testHighscore = snapshot.data
                      .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == TiposModos.Test)
                      .time /
                  1000;
              double mejorde3Highscore = snapshot.data
                      .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == TiposModos.Mejorde3)
                      .time /
                  1000;
              double mejorde5Highscore = snapshot.data
                      .firstWhere((test) => test.tipo == TiposModos.Mejorde5)
                      .time /
                  1000;
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  HighscoreTile(tipo: "Test", time: testHighscore),
                  HighscoreTile(tipo: "Mejorde3", time: mejorde3Highscore),
                  HighscoreTile(tipo: "Mejorde5", time: mejorde5Highscore),
                  //Bottom_bar(currentPage),
                ],
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
  
}

class HighscoreTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String tipo;
  final double time;

  HighscoreTile({Key key, this.tipo, this.time}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 75,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black38,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(8),
          ),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black54,
                offset: Offset(4, 8),
                blurRadius: 5,
                spreadRadius: 2),
          ],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            time <= 0
                ? tipo + ": Null"
                : tipo + ": " + time.toString() + " secs",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

y esto es el Bottom Navigation Bar que quiero implementar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: FancyBottomNavigation(
        tabs: [
          TabData(
              iconData: Icons.timeline,
              title: "Estadisticas",
              onclick: () {
                final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                    bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                fState.setPage(0);
              }),
          TabData(
              iconData: Icons.flash_on,
              title: "Home",
              onclick: () {
                final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                    bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                fState.setPage(1);
              }),
          TabData(
              iconData: Icons.settings,
              title: "Ajustes",
              onclick: () {
                final FancyBottomNavigationState fState =
                    bottomNavigationKey.currentState;
                fState.setPage(2);
              }),
        ],
        initialSelection: 0,
        inactiveIconColor: Colors.black,
        key: bottomNavigationKey,
        onTabChangedListener: (position) {
          setState(() {
            currentPage = position;

            switch (currentPage) {
              case 0:
                
              case 1:

                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MenuPrincipal()));
              
                break;

              case 2:
            }
          });
        },
      ),
```

Gracias de antemano , aunque no me escriban el codigo correcto , almenos si me pueden decir como y donde colocar las cosas me seria suficiente.

Comment: el  Bottom Navigation Bar donde lo estas incluyendo? en tu main

Comment: no, no lo incluyo al main , lo quiero incluir a otra ruta la ruta es la clase _EstadisticasState

Comment: Si quieres que el StatefulWidget Estadisticas regrese el FancyBottomNavigation, tienes que regresar un Scafold, junto con el FancyBottomNavigation, y tu body mandarlo a otro widget o una función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como es como debería de funcionar un , en este caso yo no tengo ninguna ruta.

https://codepen.io/eduardojl-the-reactor/pen/VwaMvxE

Primero.

- Donde declaras tu BottomNavigationBar es la raíz de tu ruta y debe ir dentro de un Scaffold.
- Cada BottomNavigationBarItem que agregas es el indice que te enviara el evento
- En el Evento onTabTapped, tu debes actualizar tu estado para actualizar el body, en mi ejemplo unicamente actualizo una variable _currentIndex.
- Dentro de el body cargas el nuevo widget, puede ser un StatelessWidget o un StatefulWidget, pero no otro scafold, solo la vista.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MainPage(),
    ),
  );
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

//Pagina principal de mi ruta
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        title: Text('Prueba'),
      ),
      body:
          _setbody(), // El body lo generare en base a mi variable index, se actualizara en  onTabTapped
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            //Con el set State actualizo mi indice, para actualizar mi vista
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _currentIndex, // Indice inicial a mostrar
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.access_time),
            title: new Text('Pagina 1'),
          ), //Boton Indice 0
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.list),
            title: new Text('Pagina 2'),
          ), //Boton Indice 1
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _setbody() {
    if (_currentIndex == 0) {
      return Pagina1();
    } else {
      return Pagina2();
    }
  }
}

class Pagina1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Pagina 1'),
    );
  }
}

class Pagina2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text('Pagina 2'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, la verdad es que la solucion era muy tonta.... :
Dentro de el body cargas el nuevo widget, puede ser un StatelessWidget o un StatefulWidget, pero no otro scafold, solo la vista.
Disculpa la molestias aun estoy aprendiendo -.-''